# Flutter FLcharts - How can I draw grid lines based on the bar chart titles

Tags: flutter, dart, charts

I am trying to draw a barchart using FL charts in flutter.I have custom titles for it like this

[my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNMJv.png)

I would like to get a chart like this where there is a vertical line for every bottom and left title
[my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjmmG.png)

my build method,

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: calculate(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: BarChart(
              BarChartData(
                borderData: FlBorderData(show: false),
                gridData: FlGridData(
                  show: false,
                ),
                maxY: limit,
                minY: 0,
                groupsSpace: 3,
                titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                  topTitles:
                      AxisTitles(sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
                  rightTitles:
                      AxisTitles(sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
                  bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                      sideTitles: SideTitles(
                          getTitlesWidget: bottomTitles,
                          reservedSize: 50,
                          showTitles: true)),
                  leftTitles: AxisTitles(
                      axisNameSize: 2,
                      sideTitles: SideTitles(
                          getTitlesWidget: leftTitles,
                          reservedSize: 20,
                          interval: limit / 2,
                          showTitles: true)),
                ),
                barGroups: data
                    .map(
                      (data) => BarChartGroupData(x: data.id, barRods: [
                        BarChartRodData(
                            toY: data.y.toDouble(),
                            width: 10,
                            color: Colors.purple,
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(3),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(3),
                            ))
                      ]),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.purple));
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

The calculate function calculates the bar rod data

here are the functions for the titles

```
Widget bottomTitles(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    final titles = <String>[
      '',
      '',
      '',
      '',
      '4\nAM',
      '',
      '',
      '',
      '8\nAM',
      '',
      '',
      '',
      '12\nPM',
      '',
      '',
      '',
      '4\nPM',
      '',
      '',
      '',
      '8\nPM',
      '',
      '',
      '',
    ];

    final Widget text = Text(
      titles[value.toInt()],
      style: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.grey,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 10,
      ),
    );
    return text;
  }

  Widget leftTitles(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    const style = TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10);
    String text;
    if (value == 0) {
      text = '0';
    } else {
      print(value.toInt());
      text = '${((value.toInt()) / 1000).toInt()}k';
    }
    return SideTitleWidget(
      axisSide: meta.axisSide,
      space: 4,
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: style,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have tried using the
checkToShowHorizontalLine: (value) => value % 4 == 0, which can be used to customized the grid lines but the lines do not come at the correct place